# How do I access a jpg file's tags (from "Properties") in Python?

Tags: python, metadata

In Python, I am trying to extract the "Tags" (highlighted in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciakU.png)), which is visible in the "Properties" info for a jpg image. I've tried several methods to pull the metadata from the file but none of them returns this particular field. How do I do this?

Comment: almost same question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57421335

Comment: Why not try pillow: from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS